# Can't connect to the server MySQL Server from PHP, but it works in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I checked with phpmyadmin and the query that I'm trying to do is working.

`$user` = to the username login. I see it because I echo it. So I don't think that's the error.

The error I get is

```
> PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket      
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in 
/hermes/bosweb/web161/b1615/ipg.jmdev/nmc/admin/user.php on line 14

> PHP Warning:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in 
/hermes/bosweb/web161/b1615/ipg.jmdev/nmc/admin/user.php on line 14
```

Line 14 is my query line (below), which is the piece of code that doesn't work...

Here is my code:

```
$host="link"; // Host name 
$username="username"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="nmc"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="account"; // Table name 

session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo $user . '<br>';
//[Working on PHPMyAdmin](SELECT `role` FROM `account` WHERE `username`='jean8mathieu') (Working)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `role` FROM `account` WHERE `username`='$user'");//I would like to make this work...
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT role FROM account WHERE username='jean8mathieu'"); /I try this line and did not ever work...

if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

My problem is not to connect on the server it's the query. I am able to connect to it just my query doesn't seems to work... It working for all my other page...

Comment: "A link to the server could not be established" Is your password correct?

Comment: Where is database connection? It seems you are only declaring database details

Comment: And on a sitenote: please don't use the mysql extension anymore. It is officially deprecated. You should be using either [PDO](http://www.php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/MySQLi) instead.

Comment: You don't connect to the database before querying it.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1557526) for information on the deprecation/change to PDO/MySQLi

Answer (score 4):

> Please don't use any mysql_*() function any longer, since the old MySQL library is 
>   deprecated (reached end of life).

Review [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#13944958) and choose one of the two alternatives to do MySQL related stuff.

**That said...**

You need to first of all **tell PHP how to establish a connection to the MySQL server** [using mysql_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

```
// we connect to example.com and port 3307
$link = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);

// we connect to localhost at port 3307
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Please please please explain him mysql_* are deprecated, he should start learning something else

Comment: Also **from the manual** - *"This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future."*

Comment: *"Hey, here's how you can do this with `eval` ... but don't use `eval`!"* - see how silly that looks